# CosmosDb get item by slug

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to get a single article item from container which is called `Articles` and it has partition key `/slug`

```cs
public async Task<Article> GetArticle(string slug)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _container.ReadItemAsync<Article>(slug, new PartitionKey(slug));
            return response.Resource;
        }
        catch (CosmosException) //For handling item not found and other exceptions
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[This](https://code-maze.com/azure-cosmos-db-with-asp-net-core-web-api/) is the link where I got the sample code.

In my case it returns `No Content` but I am sure there is an article with that slug.
I am wondering if the problem has to do with my container or the query?!

Comment: It searches for an item with /id=slug and /slug=slug. You have to do a query. E.g. GetItemQueryIterator

Comment: Query returns an array, is that correct?

Comment: What does your `Article` type look like?

Comment: Yes, a query will return an interator that you loop through to get the results. There is no concept of SingleOrDefault.. you handle that yourself.

And FYI you're using `ReadItemAsync` incorrectly. The first argument doesn't take a partition key. It takes an Id (this is how you'd just fetch one instead of doing a query). You can create your Container where `id` is the partition as well, but you said you have a separate property for partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadItemAsync` is using a point lookup - ie, `id` AND `partitionKey`

It's basically saying "give me the document with partitionKey x and id x"

I'm going to guess that your `Article` type looks something like this

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "slug")]
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

Id property is different to slug.

You'll need to either set your id of your document to be slug, or use a query.
If slug is immutable, and guaranteed to be unique, it could *probably* be used for ID.

Point reads using `ReadItemAsync` only *cost* 1 RU so are preferable.

Alternatively you'll need to use a query, something along these lines.

```
var slug = "some-slug";

using (FeedIterator<Article> feedIterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<Article>(
    $"select * from Article a where a.slug == {slug}",
    null,
    new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(slug)}))
{
    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach(var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            //do something with Article
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct, they are not the same. In this case I should use query instead?

Comment: As always, it depends - on number of docs, size of partition, etc... Personally, I'd look at using slug as the ID if it's immutable?